# Ruby Selenium Web Driver: find xpath elements without throwing NoSuchElementException

Tags: ruby, selenium, xpath, selenium-chromedriver

I have a below html which am trying to test using ruby selenium web driver

```
<div class="container-fluid container-results">
    <div class="result-row" id="0">
        <ul>
            <li class="process-status-column upload-success-icon">
                <svg class="glyphicon-upload-green" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#doc_upload"></use>
                </svg>
            </li>
            <li class="file-label-column"><span>validated.txt</span></li>
            <li class="client-company-column"><span>test-client</span></li>
            <li class="reference-column"><span>Ref001</span></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="result-row" id="1">
        <ul>
            <li class="process-status-column upload-error-icon">
                <svg class="glyphicon-exclamation" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#exclamation"></use>
                </svg>
            </li>
            <li class="file-label-column"><span>Error.txt</span>
                <div class="attachment-row">This invoice contains an error</div>
            </li>
            <li class="client-company-column"><span>test-client</span></li>
            <li class="reference-column"><span>Ref002</span></li>            
        </ul>
    </div>   
    <div class="result-row" id="2">
        <ul>
            <li class="process-status-column upload-pending-icon">
                <svg class="glyphicon-spin" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
                    <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#refresh"></use>
                </svg>
            </li>
            <li class="file-label-column"><span>Pending.txt</span></li>
            <li class="client-company-column"></li>
            <li class="reference-column"></li>            
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to find the `ul` element as `selectedLine` variable, which matches the `span` value as per the input parameter `unique_field_value`

```
selectedLine = nil
rows = driver.find_elements(:css => "div.container-fluid.container-results >div.result-row >ul")
rows.each do |row|
   element = row.find_element(:xpath => "./li/span[contains(., '#{unique_field_value.to_s.strip}')]")
  if(!element.nil?)
    selectedLine = row
  end
end
```

Above code works fine if I pass  `validated.txt` as parameter value `unique_field_value`  but if I pass `Error.txt` or `Pending.txt` am getttig below exception

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"./li/span[contains(., 'Error.txt')]"} (org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException)
```

My code is trying to find the `span` element matching `unique_field_value` parameter in first iteration of the `rows` and throwning exception if it doesnt find one, how do I continue the iteration over all the elements of `rows` without throwing `NoSuchElementException` exception

Comment: Could you see if `element = row.find_element(:xpath => '//*[text()="#{unique_field_value.to_s.strip}"]')` matches some element?

Comment: Stylistically, we don't use camelCase for variables or methods in Ruby. ItIsAReadabilityThing, so `selectedLine` should be `selected_line`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rows.each do |row|
  element = row.find_element(:xpath => "./li/span[contains(., '#{unique_field_value.to_s.strip.downcase}')]")
  if(!element.nil?)
    selectedLine = row
end
```

Answer (score 0):

got it working with below code

```
rows.each do |row|
    elements = row.find_elements(:xpath => "./li/span[contains(., '#{unique_field_value.to_s.strip}')]")
    if (elements.length > 0)
      selectedLine = row
    end
  end
```